# How can I create a wrapper for the Export attribute when using MEF with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mef

I have an application that uses [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) along with ASP.NET MVC 5. This architecture allows me to have a pluggable design where I can build multiple applications and run all of them into one master application. It also allowed me to have one central place for authentication and permission validation/loading.

For MVC 5 to work with MEF, each controller must have a unique export value. Therefore, I have to add these two line codes to each of my controller

```
[Export("SomeUniqueValue1", typeof(IController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
```

To make the export value unique to each plugin, I like to concatenate the plugin name to the export values. so instead of using the 2 lines above, I'll use something like this instead

```
[Export("PluginName.SomeUniqueValue1", typeof(IController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
```

Now, I am hoping to save some coding time by eliminating the 2 lines of code above so a single like. I am hoping something like the line below

```
[MefExport("SomeUniqueValue1")]
```

Then the `MefExport` class, will handle the concatenation of the plugin name to the provided name and somehow calls the `Export` class and the `PartCreationPolicy`

How can I create a class "i.e. MefExport" that extends `Export` class which allows me to add the plugin name and call the `Export` and the `PartCreationPolicy`?

This is what I started with

```
public class MefExport : ExportAttribute
{
    public MefExport(string exportName)
    {
        string finalExportValue = Helpers.GetPluginName() + exportName;

        new ExportAttribute(finalExportValue, typeof(IController));
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer given by Will Ray, is a good solution for your problem, but I would suggest you to be more descriptive with your export attribute. Imo, `[MEFExport]` could be better named as something like `[MEFControllerExport]` or `[ControllerExport]`. That way you will have room for more plugin definitions later without the problem of getting ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can reasonably combine both attributes into one. The `PartCreationPolicyAttribute` is a sealed class and code which is looking for that attribute will need precisely that type.

However, you could simplify the first bit by calling the base class with your calculated values:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class MefExportAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public MefExportAttribute(string exportName)
        : base(GetContractName(exportName), typeof(IController))
    {
    }

    private static string GetContractName(string exportName)
    {
        return Helpers.GetPluginName() + exportName;
    }
}
```

(I just copied the `ExportAttribute`'s `AttributeUsage` values - you may have different needs for this custom attribute.)

Comment: Thank you for this. What does this line do? `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]`

Comment: @Jaylen It defines how the attribute is allowed to be used in the code. For this instance, you could say that "The MefAttribute can be used on classes, methods, properties and fields. It can be used more than once on any one of these things. Classes which override or inherit from these things do not inherit this attribute."

Comment: I get an error when using this attribute `No exports were found that match the constraint:
ContractName SomeUniqueValue
RequiredTypeIdentity System.Web.Mvc.IController`

Comment: @Jaylen What does your `ImportAttribute` look like? It use the unique key and also be of type `IController`.

Comment: I have this method `public static T GetInstance<T>(string contractName = null)
        {
            if (CompositionContainer == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contractName))
            {
                return CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>(contractName);
            }

            return CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();
        }`

Comment: and I call that method like so `public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            var controller = Bootstrapper.GetInstance<IController>(controllerName);

            if (controller == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Controller not found!");
            }

            return controller;
        }`

Comment: @Jaylen Check to make sure your `IController` is being registered with the name that you are using in that method. They might not be matching.

Comment: Both are using the `IController` found in the `using System.Web.Mvc;` space

Comment: @Jaylen You need to resolve them with the proper name. It must be whatever `GetContractName` generates. If the names don't match it will error.